# how can i simplify this code? is there a way to transform this into a for loop?

Tags: python, simplify

How can i simplify this code? Is there a way to transform this into a for loop?
I have tried some for loops but nothing works or is shorter than this and is more effective.

This is the code i want to optimize:

```
if selection == 1:
    function1
elif selection == 2:
    function2
elif selection == 3:
    function3
elif selection == 4:
    function4
```

Comment: `if selection in (1, 2, 3, 4):` or `if 1 <= selection <= 4:`

Comment: Why would you want a loop? You're not doing anything repeatedly.

Comment: It depends on what you plan to substitute your`pass` statements with.  Right now your code does nothing.

Comment: I just want to execute a function, nothing special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to execute a different function based on the selection's value. A nice way to do that is by having a dictionary with the values and the functions you want to call which acts as map between the selection and the function. For example:

```
functions = {'1': function1, '2': function2, '3': function3}
```

and then if execute the the function based on the selection:

```
functions[selection]()
```

And you can improve it a little by adding some error handling in case the key does not exist in the dictionary

Comment: Keep in mind that dictionary keys can be integers, and `selection` appears to be an int in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can store the functions in a list as objects

```
[function1, function2, function3, function4][selection - 1]()
```

However, this isn't really readable, so not recommended. You cannot use loops because your code doesn't do any actions repetitively